# How to remove some lines from a file which contains directory paths but keep some roots in bash

Tags: bash

I have a file containing paths to some directories I want to remove like follows:

```
/path/to/dir/datadir1
/path/to/dir/datadir1/subdir1/
/path/to/dir/datadir1/subdir1/subdir2/subdir3
...
/path/to/dir/datadir2
/path/to/dir/datadir2/subdir1/
/path/to/dir/datadir2/subdir1/subdir2/subdir3
...
/path/to/dir/datadir3
/path/to/dir/datadir3/subdir1/
/path/to/dir/datadir3/subdir1/subdir2/subdir3
...
```

I need to exclude from this file all the paths with subdirectories. (e.g. /path/to/dir/datadir2/subdir1/ and /path/to/dir/datadir2/subdir1/subdir2/subdir3)

I've tried two approaches:

```
while read A
do
    read B
    [ "$A" != "$B" ] &&  grep -v "^$B$" directories.txt > dir1.txt
    test dir1.txt && mv dir1.txt directories.txt
done < directories.txt
```

This one works partially. It is removing only the longest path: /path/to/dir/datadir2/subdir1/subdir2/subdir3
If I add it in a function and I use it to loop again and again in the end I will only have only the first row in my file.

second

```
for k in `cat directories.txt`; do
    echo $k
    for m in `cat directories.txt`; do
    echo "m este --->$m"
        if [[ m != k ]]; then
            grep -v "^${k}$" directories.txt  > tmp.txt
            test tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt directories.txt
        fi
    done
done
```

This one is removing all lines in the file.
Sometimes the length of the path I want to keep may be longer, so it is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk`:

```
$ awk -F/ 'NF<6' file
/path/to/dir/datadir1
...
/path/to/dir/datadir2
...
/path/to/dir/datadir3
```

The number `6` represent the number of folders. Adjust it to any number that's convenient for you.

Comment: this approach works pretty nice but sometimes the number of fields is dynamic and can change from a machine to another

Comment: @AdrianIacob your question doesn't state that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `grep` for this:

```
grep -vE '^/.+/.+/.+/.+/' directories.txt > directories.txt.filtered
```

This would eliminated all directories that are deeper than four levels.

---

Take a look at [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)